# Combining bind and return

Tags: haskell

Consider:

```
x `f` y = x >>= (return . y)
```

This function `f` seems very similar to `<$>` and `flip liftM` but `<$>` doesn't seem to work and I'd have to define an infix operator for `flip liftM` to make it look nice and I'm presuming one already exists?

Is there a function like what I've described and what is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is `flip liftM`, but not `<$>`.  It's also almost exactly the same as `flip <$>`, but the latter is for the `Functor` typeclass, not `Monad`.  (In the latest standard libraries the relationship between `Functor` and `Monad` is not yet reflected in the typeclass hierarchy, [but it will be](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)).

If you want to find where this is defined, you go to [FP Complete's Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle), enter the type you are looking for

```
Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b
```

and discover [it is defined in lens](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/lens/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v%3a-60--38--62-).

Comment: Is there anyway to bring the new Monad/Functor hierarchy into place? i.e. a Prelude replacement, language pragma or simply defining it manually?

Comment: There's no real point to doing it "by hand" if you want to keep compatibility with existing code.  You'd have to introduce new classes, and either wrap and unwrap every function that you want to use which uses the old classes, or wrap and unwrap values with new instances every time you pass them to functions expecting the old instances.  This completely defeats the point of the Functor-Applicative-Monad proposal, which is to make code simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Your function

```
x `f` y = x >>= (return . y)
```

is equivalent to `flip fmap`, so if you don't mind swapping the order, you can `import Data.Functor`, define `fmap` and write it as

```
y <$> x
```

(There's no need to wait for `Functor` to be a superclass of `Monad`; you can go ahead today and define it.)

This has nice precedence so you can write stuff like

```
munge = Just . remove bits . add things <$> operation 1 
            >>= increase something <$> operation 2
```

instead of

```
munge' = do
     thing1 <- operation 1
     let thing2 = Just . remove bits. add things $ thing1
     thing3 <- operation 2
     return . increase something $ thing3
```

but even nicer, if you `import Control.Applicative` instead (which also exports `<$>`), you can combine multiple things, for example:

```
addLine = (+) <$> readLine <*> readLine >>= print
```

instead of

```
addLine' = do
    one <- readLine
    two <- readLine
    print (one + two)
```

### Future-proofing your code

If [the Functor-Applicative-proposal](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) goes ahead, you'll have to make all your Monads Applicatives (and hence Functors). You may as well start now.

If your Monad isn't already an Applicative, you can define `pure = return` and

```
mf <*> mx = do
   f <- mf
   x <- mx
   return (f x)
```

If it's not a Functor, you can define

```
fmap f mx = do
   x <- mx
   return (f x)
```

The proposal suggests using `(<*>) = ap` and `fmap = liftM`, both from `Control.Monad`, but the definitions above are easy too, and you may well find it even easier in your own Monad.

Answer (score 1):

`Data.Generics.Serialization.Standard` exports `(>>$)` which is defined as `flip liftM`. Not exactly a general-purpose module to depend upon, but you can if you want to. I've seen similar definitions in other application-specific modules. This is an indication that no general-purpose module defines such a function.

The least painful solution is probably to define your own, at least until the big Monad hierarchy overhaul happens.